# Booking System MongoDB, Apollo prevent bookings on same room

Tags: mongodb, concurrency

I try to implement a room booking system with MongoDB as database, Apollo GraphQL and express server.

I have to collections in my database: one for the rooms and one for bookings. To check for availability the system finds all bookings currently in the db and checks which room are availability for the specified time slot.
If the system books a room, it inserts a new record in the db.

The problem is the following scenario, two booking requests for the same room at the same time:

```
booking request 1 -> check for available rooms
booking request 2 -> check for available rooms
booking request 1 -> read request success (display available rooms)
booking request 2 -> read request success (display available rooms)
booking request 1 -> write a new record to the db (new booking)
booking request 2 -> write a new record to the db (new booking) but this conflicts with booking 1.
```

How can I guarantee that one room is never has to conflicting bookings?

The problem is, that I have one request for availability and and another statement writing the booking to the db.

Comment: I think what I really mean is, is there a way to prevent phantoms reads in order to not having double-bookings ?

Answer (score 0):

i did the same thing with postgres, but im sure MongoDB have the same functionality.

in your booking table, the key will be combination of room and date-range.

you can define constrain on the table, that raw with the same room_id cannot have overlap
date-range.

when you want to insert new booking, just insert it, and the db should avoid insert raw that overlap with the time range(because of the constraint)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer..
As far as I know this kind of constraints are not possible with MongoDB. I might use the wrong technology stack and should switch to an sql database. But in my opinion this kind of simple booking system should be possible with MongoDB, am I wrong?!